# Find match in string and get everything expect match

Tags: regex

Hello i would like to find for example word like this "total-games" in string like "total-games-over-19-5", so i need to check if total-games exists in string, if exists, then get everything before and behind this word, is it possible? Thanks for any ideas! :) I tried to use preg_match but regex is kinda problem for me.

---

Sorry i forgot i need it in PHP language, anyway my regular expression is then (.*)total-games(.*) ?

Basically i can use something like

```
if(preg_match('(.*)total-games(.*)',$string, $matches))
{
   // and get matches like $matches[0] .. etc?
}
```

PS: sir your regular expression doesnt work for me like this, i used preg_match function if its somehow connected.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression should be `(.*)total-games(.*)` and then based on programming language you can extract the groups.
Like in Python in would be

```
import re
str = "total-games-over-19-5"
r = re.compile(r"(.*)total-games(.*)")
m = re.match(r, str)
print(m.group(1) + "---" + m.group(2))
```

Here `m.group(1)` would be empty because there is nothing before total-games in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
(.*)total-games(.*)|.*
```

which always matches, but groups 1 and 2, which contain the "before" and "after" text, will be blank if the input doesn't contain "total-games".